# Meteor users and backbone very slow

Tags: performance, backbone.js, meteor

I created a project for easy content sharing. You can look at my project here:
[SharingProject](http://pagesharingproject.meteor.com/)

You can use user@example.com with 123456 as password to test the site as verified user. Of course the site has some bugs yet...

I used the meteor user package and the backbone package to navigate through the pages.
On localhost, there is no problem. For testing I uploaded the project to the meteor server. Now while I am logged in and navigating through the pages, every time I navigate to a new page the app 'checks' the user on client side because of the url change. This is annoying...

Of course I could navigate through the pages only calling Session.set('page_id', ..) but my goal is to be able to send people an url to a specific page on the server.

The code is similar to the one in the todos example from the meteor page:

```
Meteor.subscribe('pages', function () {
    if (!Session.get('page_id')) {
    var page = Pages.findOne({}, {sort: {owner: -1}});
    if (page)
      Router.setPage(page._id);
  }
});

...

var PagesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    ":page_id": "main"
  },
  main: function (page_id) {
    Session.set("page_id", page_id);
  },
  setPage: function (page_id) {
    this.navigate(page_id, true);
  }
});

Router = new PagesRouter;

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Why I am asking here: I searched the web and can't find anyone with the same problem. So either nobody tried this before or there is a simple solution for this?

Edit: How I call the pages

```
<template name="pages"> 
    {{#each pages}}
        <p><a href="/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a>
        {{#if isauthor}}
            <a class="delPage" href="javascript:delPage('{{_id}}')">delete</a>
        {{/if}}
        </p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem, changing (true)

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

to (false)

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: false});
});
```

and of course adding an anchor like Mubix suggested. Thanks for the hint!
It is up to date on the site mentioned above.

I spend some time today on the backbone documentation, but I can't imagine why this is working? Especially I am wondering why

```
{hashChange: false}
```

doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are rendering the page links but a link like this :

http://pagesharingproject.meteor.com/a1fbacba-0ddf-4077-a653-294b428bbfb8

should read like:

http://pagesharingproject.meteor.com/#a1fbacba-0ddf-4077-a653-294b428bbfb8

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "should read"? The router? I will edit my question and show you how I call the pages. If I call href="/#{{_id}}" nothing happens... So far I read some examples working with backbone router. The problem is: Not the whole page should be rendered, only the content. So I decided to block the navigation of the browser through this line: this.navigate(page_id, true); But it's still the same? So is there a possibility to block the "reload" of the page by clicking the link, but still changing the Session "page_id" according to the url?

Comment: I feel that `href="/#{{_id}}"` should definitely work. To test this theory I opened a page and copied the link for another page and pasted it in the address bar then I manually put the # and pressed entered. The new page was loaded without refresh.

Comment: Sorry I tried again by modifying the link in dev tools and it doesn't work :(

Comment: I tried it in the address bar and it does not even work there for me...? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Can you try your route as `"/:page_id": "main"` .. i.e. with the slash.

Comment: Ok I tried: `"/:page_id": "main"` , `":/page_id": "main"` in combination with `href="{{_id}}"` , `href="#{{_id}}"` , `href="/#{{_id}}"` and `href="/{{_id}}"` and some more confusing combinations... Nothing in the contentfield has been loaded... and the reload still has been there.